# interpolate 3D data in two dimensions with griddata in python

Tags: python, scipy

so this is a problem that I have been trying to solve in a nice way for a while.

Basically, I have some data (spectra, i.e. intensities for 1000 different wavelengths) and these depend on two parameters Z and A, with dimensions 25 and 300. My data is thus an array of dimensions 1000x25x300. And I have two arrays containing the different values for A and Z.

What I want to do, is to find an interpolated spectrum (i.e. 1000 points with intensities) for arbitrary values of A and Z within the ranges of my data.

I feel like scipy griddata should be able to do this, but I cant quite figure out the proper way to do this.

Currently I have:

> - Z - An array of 25 measurements of parameter Z
> - A - An array of 300 measurements of parameter A
> - Spec_data - The actual spectra, an array of 1000 x 25 x 300
> - p_A - the A value that I want to interpolate to
> - p_Z - the Z value that I want to interpolate to

What I want:

> - out_spec - a spectrum (of length 1000) for p_A and p_Z.

I have found solutions to similar problems but nothing exactly like this. I would really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you want, at least this example works. I changed the size of the Spec_data to `(20, 5, 10)` instead of `(1000, 25, 300)` because such a big array can be time consuming to interpolate.

```
A = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
Z = np.linspace(1, 5, 5)
Spec_data = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(20,len(Z),len(A)))
p_A = 1.5
p_Z = 1.5

import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d

AA, ZZ = np.meshgrid(A,Z)
Spec_data_pAZ = np.ones(shape=Spec_data_pAZ.shape[0]) * np.nan
for i in range(len(Spec_data_pAZ)):
    f = interp2d(AA, ZZ, Spec_data[i])
    Spec_data_pAZ[i] = f([p_A],[p_Z])

print(Spec_data[0])
print(Spec_data_pAZ[0])

>>> [[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1]
 [1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1]]
>>> 0.24999999999999994
```

Comment: this solution does seem to work (even though it sometimes gives slightly strange results). However, it seems to be really slow for larger sets of data. I need something more efficient than this.

Comment: if you just need the interpolated value of one point you could reduce the array to the 4 points closest to the point you are interested in. In the interpolation only these values are used

Comment: yes, I guess I could, thanks. However, as I stated in the question, I feel like griddata should be able to do this, and in a way that would be way less manual.